# Install OpenSSH Server in Dockerfile via COPY --from=

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openssh

In a bid to create a Dockerfile which results in an as minimal as possible image size while also keeping it readable, I'm writing a Dockerfile where all installs are via the `COPY --from=` syntax.

So for example I have this so far

```
FROM alpine/git:2.40.1 AS git_binary
FROM linuxserver/openssh-server:amd64-version-9.3_p2-r0 AS openssh_server_binary 
FROM debian:12.1-slim

# User setup
ENV USER dev
RUN adduser $USER
USER $USER
WORKDIR /home/$USER

# Install Git
COPY --from=git_binary /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git
COPY --from=git_binary /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
COPY --from=git_binary /usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 /usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0
COPY --from=git_binary /lib/libz.so.1 /lib/libz.so.1

# Install OpenSSH Server
COPY --from=openssh_server_binary # Not sure what I need to copy here
```

which successfully adds git from a binary. I used the `ldd` CLI to determine the exact library files required by the git binary, and I'm assuming I should be able to do the same for open ssh, but first I need to know what commands I should actually be copying over. Perhaps I should be using a different image than `linuxserver/openssh-server`?

Note: I'm not considering any package manager installation answers valid here (ex via apk or apt install). I am specifically asking for how to install via Dockerfile COPY only.

Comment: The openssh server is called `sshd`.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I'm not seeing that executable in the image I mentioned

Comment: If you look in that image, you'll find `/usr/sbin/sshd.pam`, but unclear why you picked that image. Since you're already using `alpine`; why not just install the `openssh` package in an alpine build stage and then copy the `sshd` binary from there?

Comment: That might make more sense. Also thanks I missed the .pam file. Would it not generally be faster (faster build time) to copy a prebuilt version rather than installing?

Comment: It may be slightly faster, although I don't think the difference is going to be all that significant in this case. Another question: if you're using an alpine-based source image for the git and ssh binaries, why are you you using a Debian based image for the final stage?

Answer (score 1):

You're going through a lot of trouble to build something of a franken-image: a combination of MUSL-libc alpine linux packages and a Debian glibc-based image...and you're not saving yourself any space. If we take your Dockerfile as is (but fix the sshd bit), we end up with:

```
$ docker image ls example-1
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
example-1    latest    c35c32b5b451   2 minutes ago   79.9MB
```

But if we just build from an Alpine base, like this:

```
FROM alpine:3

RUN apk add git openssh
```

We end up with:

```
$ docker image ls example-2
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
example-2    latest    e03637efb7f5   2 minutes ago   26.2MB
```

So that's 65% smaller, and unlike the previous image:

- It works.Your existing Dockerfile, with alpine-sshd installed on a Debian image, runs into all sorts of symbol errors because you're missing additional shared libraries.
- The build time is almost identical (I'm seeing around 1.5 seconds for the your Dockerfile, and about 1.8 seconds for the one I've shown here).

Comment: I agree it looks like my image is larger mainly due to my lack of knowledge up until now about Alpine vs Debian. I'm trying this Dockerfile again based off of Alpine + this COPY approach rather than installing. I think the result should be a smaller image + faster build.